# Video.js + AJAX + Chrome bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, html5-video

So I have a bug that only appears for some people and so far only in chrome. It appears to work fine in every other browser.

Here's the JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DDZGa/3/

In the bottom right window, click the Add link to add a video. Hit play. Then add another video and hit play. So far 50% of people I have test this (including myself) get the loading animation indefinitely on the second video, the rest seem to have no problems. I have not been able to isolate it to any particular version of chrome. It seems random. Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: I have the problem, but I can't get to know why it happens...

Comment: Don't forget to mention which version of Chrome you're referring to.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with Google Chrome.

I tried `preload="none"` on video tag and after that video works much better.